# FileOutputStream not writing to files

Tags: java, io

I have written this program trying to write to a text file,but nothing is happening after executing the program.Can you suggest how to specify filepath? I am using eclipse and have created a file "out.txt" in the same default package where my class is.

```
import java.io.*;
public class InputOutput {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    int i;
    //File file=new File("inputd");
    //File file0=new File("out");
    FileInputStream fin=null;
    //FileOutputStream fout=null;
    DataOutputStream fout=null;



    //copy the file

    try
    {
        //fin=new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        fout=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));
        //fout=new FileOutputStream("out.txt");

        fout.write(1);
        fout.write(100);
        fout.write(1000);


    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("I/O Error" + ioe);
    }

    finally {

        if (fout != null) {
           fout.close();
        }

    //fin.close();

}
}
}
```

Comment: The file should appear in your project's main folder, not in the package that your class is in. Your application creates the file, you don't need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be automatically created and will be in your projects root folder. 
Also, if you don't see the file in your project in Eclipse, click on your project in the project explorer and press F5 or right click on your project and select refresh.